# Inequality in proof that $ X_n \overset{P} \to X \Rightarrow X_n \overset{d} \to X $

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

I am looking at the proof of convergence in probability implying convergence in distribution. The proof begins by stating that if $X_n \leq x$ then either $ X \leq x + \epsilon $ or $ |X_n - X| > \epsilon $. I can't quite see this implication;

$ X_n \leq x \Rightarrow X \leq x + \epsilon$ or $ X > x + \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow X \leq x + \epsilon$ or $ X - X_n \geq X - x > \epsilon $

but how do I obtain $X_n - X > \epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_n \leq x$ and $X > x + \epsilon$, then $|X_n-X| = X-X_n$.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Pr}(X_{n}\leq x) &= \operatorname{Pr}(X_{n}\leq x,\ X\leq x+\varepsilon) + \operatorname{Pr}(X_{n}\leq x,\ X>x+\varepsilon) \\
      &\leq \operatorname{Pr}(X\leq a+\varepsilon) + \operatorname{Pr}(X_{n}-X\leq x-X,\ x-X<-\varepsilon) \\
      &\leq \operatorname{Pr}(X\leq x+\varepsilon) + \operatorname{Pr}(X_{n}-X<-\varepsilon) \\
      &\leq \operatorname{Pr}(X\leq x+\varepsilon) + \operatorname{Pr}(X_{n}-X<-\varepsilon) + \operatorname{Pr}(X_{n}-X>\varepsilon)\\
      &= \operatorname{Pr}(X\leq x+\varepsilon) + \operatorname{Pr}(|X_{n}-X|>\varepsilon)
  \end{align}.$

And it should be very easy from here, but let me know if you get stuck again.